# NullPointerException in linkedlist

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, linked-list, queue

```
  1 // This program helps staff manage customers'
  2 // orders and decide who should be given a ready dish.
  3 
  4 import java.util.*;
  5 
  6 // This class represents all orders of customers
  7 class ListOrder {
  8 
  9     // Data member
 10     private int numDishes;
 11     // All dishes which the restaurant offers
 12     private String[] dishes;
 13     // Each dish has a queue of customers who ordered this dish
 14     // All such queues are put inside an ArrayList called dishQueues
 15     private ArrayList<Queue<Integer>> dishQueues;
 16 
 17     // Constructor
 18     public ListOrder(int numDishes, Scanner sc) {
 19         this.numDishes = numDishes;
 20         dishes = new String[this.numDishes];
 21         ArrayList<Queue<Integer>> dishQueues = new ArrayList<Queue<Integer>>();
 22         for(int i=0;i<this.numDishes;i++)   {
 23             dishes[i] = new String(sc.nextLine());
 24             dishQueues.add(new LinkedList<Integer>());
 25         }
 26     }
 27 
 28     // Add new order to the list
 29     public void addNewOrder(int dishID, int tag) {
 30         dishQueues.get(dishID-1).offer(new Integer(tag));
 31     }   
 32     
 33     // Process food when it is ready
 34     // Return the customer who currently ordered for the dish
 35     // if there is no customer order for this dish return -1
 36     public int processReadyFood(int dishID) {
 37         int ready=0;
 38         if (dishQueues.get(dishID-1).peek() == null)
 39             return -1;
 40         else    
 41             ready = dishQueues.get(dishID-1).poll();
 42             
 43         return ready;
 44     }   
 45     
 46     // Get dish's name
 47     public String getDishName(int dishID) {
 48         return dishes[dishID-1];
 49     }   
 50     
 51 }
 52 
 53 public class QuickEat {
 54 
 55     public static void main(String [] args) {
 56     
 57         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 58         int numDishes = sc.nextInt();
 59         String command; 
 60         sc.nextLine();
 61 
 62         // Create the list order of food
 63         ListOrder listOrder = new ListOrder(numDishes, sc);
 64 
 65         int noOfCommands = sc.nextInt();
 66         sc.nextLine();
 67 
 68         // Process commands
 69         for(int i=0; i<noOfCommands;i++)    {
 70             command = sc.next();
 71             if(command.equals("Order")) {
 72                 int tag = sc.nextInt();
 73                 int numOfDishes = sc.nextInt();
 74                 for(i=0;i<numOfDishes;i++)
 75                     listOrder.addNewOrder(sc.nextInt(),tag);
 76             }
 77             else if(command.equals("Ready"))    {
 78                 int dishID = sc.nextInt();
 79                 int customer = listOrder.processReadyFood(dishID);
 80                 if(customer == -1)
 81                     System.out.println("Throw away " + listOrder.getDishName(dishID));
 82                 else
 83                     System.out.println(listOrder.getDishName(dishID) + " ready to be served to Tag " + customer);
 84             }
 85         }
 86     }
 87 }
```

I don't have much problem with other parts of the code but if there is please do highlight to me! The main problem I get is that when I enter in

```
3
Fish n Chips
Chicken Chop
Grilled Salmon
9
Order 1 2 1 3
```

I get this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at ListOrder.addNewOrder(QuickEat.java:30)
        at QuickEat.main(QuickEat.java:75)
```

I've checked and it's nothing wrong with the dishID-1 but the offer method but I still don't know what the problem is!!!! :(((( HELP! :(

Comment: The only possible explanation is that either `dishQueues` is `null` or `dishQueues.get(dishID-1)` returns `null`.  Looking at the code it's the former

Comment: Oh yea that makes sense, how do I initialise it then or at least make it non null.

Comment: Read @Octopus' answer below

Comment: yea i know but how do i instantiate queues in the arraylist of <queue<integer>> since it is abstract?

Comment: Use one of the concrete implementations lists in the JavaDocs - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html

Comment: sry tbh that doesnt help at all. I have no idea what you're talking about. I've tried
Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer>();
then
dishQueues.add(q) but still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

You have created the referrence of  `private ArrayList<Queue<Integer>> dishQueues;` but you have not created an object

do like this       `private ArrayList<Queue<Integer>> dishQueues=new ArrayList<Queue<Integer>> ;`

Comment: sorry i corrected my code. let me correct my question

Comment: @user3274993 In line 21 you have initialized dishQueues but that is for Listorder() ,you have to reinitialize for addNewOrder() also

Answer (score 0):

`dishQueues` is `null`. Initialize the list like this

`private ArrayList<Queue<Integer>> dishQueues = new ArrayList<Queue<Integer>>();`

**After your update in the question**, the problem should be now with

`dishQueues.get(dishID-1)` being `null`

Change your `addNewOrder` method code to check for `null` and initialize a new Queue instance if not exists

```
     public void addNewOrder(int dishID, int tag) {
         if(dishQueues.get(dishID-1) == null)
           dishQueues.get(dishID-1) = new LinkedList<Integer>();
         dishQueues.get(dishID-1).offer(new Integer(tag));
     }
```

You have just created an `ArrayList` instance which will contain Queue Objects. I don't see anywhere creation of any `Queue` instances or any references to `Queue` instances to add to the list. So, create a new / refer instance of any class implementing `Queue`  for every index in the list. Otherwise, it would be `null` causing **NPE**

**UPDATE 2**

When i see your question again this morning, i saw there is member variable  shadowing in the constructor.

`ArrayList<Queue<Integer>> dishQueues = new ArrayList<Queue<Integer>>();`. You are creating a local variable which has scope only within the constructor, which is not member variable. Use `this` for denoting instance members always. This will help in maintainance of the code and increase readability. You need to change the constructor like this

```
// Constructor
 18     public ListOrder(int numDishes, Scanner sc) {
 19         this.numDishes = numDishes;
 20         dishes = new String[this.numDishes];
            //this will initialize the member variable `dishQueues` in ListOrder
 21         this.dishQueues = new ArrayList<Queue<Integer>>();
 22         for(int i=0;i<this.numDishes;i++)   {
 23             dishes[i] = new String(sc.nextLine());
 24             dishQueues.add(new LinkedList<Integer>());
 25         }
 26     }
```

Hope you understand it now!

Comment: i corrected my code but i didn't update it in the question. thanks bro but thats not the main problem i was dealing with :(

Comment: I have updated answer. Can you try it? I'm gonna leave for the day. The problem should be mostly it. Try to debug the code and you can fix these errors easily.

Comment: trying right now. I'm getting some errors. dishQueues.get(dishID-1) is stated in your answer as a variable which is incorrect i think

Comment: Alright it makes sense now. Now I have trouble trying to create instances. haha :((((

Comment: `Queue` is an interface and cannot be instantiated as shown.  You should use one of the concrete implementation listed in the JavaDocs - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html

Comment: sry tbh that doesnt help at all. I have no idea what you're talking about. I've tried Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer>(); then dishQueues.add(q) but still doesnt work

Comment: Check the *Update 2* in the answer